# scipy installation test fails test_decomp.test_eigh

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, nosetests

I have numpy, scipy, openblas installed via apt-get on ubuntu 14.10 64-bit.
numpy.test() runs without any failures, but scipy.test() fails on test_decomp.test_eigh

```
Running unit tests for scipy
NumPy version 1.9.1
NumPy is installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy
SciPy version 0.14.0
SciPy is installed in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy
Python version 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) [GCC 4.9.1]
nose version 1.3.4
....
....
....
======================================================================
FAIL: test_decomp.test_eigh('general ', 6, 'F', True, False, False, (2, 4))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
self.test(*self.arg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/linalg/tests/test_decomp.py", line 648, in eigenhproblem_general
assert_array_almost_equal(diag2_, ones(diag2_.shape[0]), DIGITS[dtype])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 842, in assert_array_almost_equal
precision=decimal)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/testing/utils.py", line 665, in assert_array_compare
raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError:
Arrays are not almost equal to 4 decimals

(mismatch 100.0%)
  x: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)
  y: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```

I thought something is wrong with my blas version, but i tried out several blas builds but had absolutely no effect on outcome of the test.
Any suggestions?

Comment: In the release notes of SciPy 0.14 at the  Backwards incompatible changes section I found the following note:
Eigenvectors in the case of generalized eigenvalue problem are normalized to unit vectors in 2-norm, rather than following the LAPACK normalization convention.

The deprecated UMFPACK wrapper in scipy.sparse.linalg has been removed due to license and install issues. If available, scikits.umfpack is still used transparently in the spsolve and factorized functions. Otherwise, SuperLU is used instead in these functions.

Maybe this has something to do with the failed test?